# Mensagem para o usuário após mudança de header

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, header

Eu estou com um pequeno problema com o PHP, eu preciso redirecionar o usuário, mas queria notifica-lo do que aconteceu, eu o redireciono com o `header()`, mas se eu tento mandar algo antes o `header` falha, alguma dica de como eu posso mandar uma mensagem para o `usuario` e modificar o `header`? Eu tentei mudar o `header` antes de mandar a mensagem, mas nesse caso a mensagem não foi enviada.

Eis o código que eu fiz, estou usando MySql e queria notificar o usuario quando foi cadastrado e quando houve uma falha:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $host = "localhost:8889";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "root";
    $banco = "ArrayEnterprises";
    $conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $banco);
    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $senha = md5($_POST["senha"]);
    $img = $_POST["img"];
    $inserir = "INSERT INTO Usuario (nome, email, senha, foto) VALUES('{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$senha}', '{$img}')";
     if($query = mysqli_query($conexao, $inserir)){
        if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao) > 0){
            header("location: index.html");
            echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Cadastrou!');</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('houve um erro');</script>";
        header("location: cadastro.html");
    }
    mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma primeira opção seria considerar o uso de sessões, armazenando a mensagem ná página de origem, e capturar essa mensagem na mesma página, ou numa outra página, depois do recirect.

```
<?php
# pagina principal
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['redirect']) && !is_numeric($_GET['redirect'])){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Redireccionado com sucesso';
    header("Location: redirect.php");
} elseif(isset($_GET['redirect']) && is_numeric($_GET['redirect'])) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Erro';
    header("Location: redirect.php");
} else {
    print "</p>Clique num dos links abaixo</p>";
}
#capturar mensagem
if(isset($_SESSION['msg']) && !empty($_SESSION['msg'])){
    print "<script>alert(\"{$_SESSION['msg']}\")</script>";
}

?>
<a href="?redirect=1">ver erro</a> | <a href="?redirect=ir">ver mensagem</a>
```

Poderias também usar o próprio javascript para redirecionar depois de mostrar o alert, fazendo o seguinte:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['redirect']) && !is_numeric($_GET['redirect'])){
    print "<script>alert('sucesso');</script>";
    print "<script>location.href='redirect1.php';</script>";
} elseif(isset($_GET['redirect']) && is_numeric($_GET['redirect'])) {
    print "<script>alert('erro');</script>";
    print "<script>location.href='redirect1.php';</script>";
} else {
    print "</p>Clique num dos links abaixo</p>";
}


?>
<a href="?redirect=1">ver erro</a> | <a href="?redirect=ir">ver mensagem</a>
```

Numa terceira opção, poderias ainda imprimir a mensagem nesse mesmo script, e depois fazer o redirect:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['redirect']) && !is_numeric($_GET['redirect'])){
    print "sucesso";
    print "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='redirect1.php'\", 1000);</script>";
} elseif(isset($_GET['redirect']) && is_numeric($_GET['redirect'])) {
    print "erro";
    print "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='redirect1.php'\", 1000);</script>";
} else {
    print "</p>Clique num dos links abaixo</p>";
}


?>
<a href="?redirect=1">ver erro</a> | <a href="?redirect=ir">ver mensagem</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o amigo falou anteriormente use:

```
$_SESSION['mensagem'] = 'mensagem';
```

Em seguida faça seu header, e na pagina redirecionada mostre a session:

```
echo $_SESSION['mensagem']
```