# Mensagem de sucesso após o preenchimento do form com HTML e PHP

Tags: php, html, formulário, validação

Eu estou criando um cadastro simples de clientes através de um formulário. Entretanto, não estou conseguindo colocar uma mensagem de "Cadastrado com Sucesso" na mesma página deste formulário. A validação deste formulário, antes do envio ao Banco de Dados, eu fiz em PHP, conforme o código abaixo:

index.php - Onde está o formulário e onde estou tentando colocar a mensagem.

```
            <form method="post" name="formCadastro" action="inserir_dados.php" >

            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Seu nome completo"

                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['value_nome'])){
                            echo "value='".$_SESSION['value_nome']."'";
                            unset($_SESSION['value_nome']);
                        }
                     ?>>
                     <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['vazio_nome'])){
                            echo "<p style='color: #b63e3e;position: relative; top:43px'>".$_SESSION['vazio_nome']."</p>";
                            unset($_SESSION['vazio_nome']);
                        }
                     ?>             

            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email comercial"

                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['value_email'])){
                            echo "value='".$_SESSION['value_email']."'";
                            unset($_SESSION['value_email']);
                        }
                     ?>>
                     <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['vazio_email'])){
                            echo "<p style='color: #b63e3e;position: relative; top:43px'>".$_SESSION['vazio_email']."</p>";
                            unset($_SESSION['vazio_email']);
                        }
                     ?>                     

            <br><br><br>
            <input type="text" id ="fone" name="fone" placeholder="Telefone com DDD"

                    <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['value_fone'])){
                            echo "value='".$_SESSION['value_fone']."'";
                            unset($_SESSION['value_fone']);
                        }
                     ?>>
                     <?php
                        if(!empty($_SESSION['vazio_fone'])){
                            echo "<p style='font-family: Helvetica Neue; color: #b63e3e;position: relative; top:43px'>".$_SESSION['vazio_fone']."</p>";
                            unset($_SESSION['vazio_fone']);
                        }
                     ?>     

            <br><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">

        </form>
```

inserir_dados.php - O código em PHP para validar e inserir os dados no BD.

```
<?php
```

session_start();

```
include_once 'conexao.php';

$nome = null;
$email = null;
$fone = null;
$verifica_insert= null;

if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
    $_SESSION['vazio_nome'] = "Campo nome é obrigatório";
        $verifica_insert= " ";
}else{
    $_SESSION['value_nome'] = $_POST['nome'];
}

if(empty($_POST['email'])){
    $_SESSION['vazio_email'] = "Campo e-mail é obrigatório";
    $verifica_insert= " ";
}else{
    $_SESSION['value_email'] = $_POST['email'];
}

if(empty($_POST['fone'])){
    $_SESSION['vazio_fone'] = "Campo e-mail é obrigatório";
    $verifica_insert= " ";
}else{
    $_SESSION['value_fone'] = $_POST['fone'];
}

if ($verifica_insert != " "){

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['nome']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['email']);
$fone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao, $_POST['fone']);

$result_sql = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome,email,fone) VALUES ('$nome','$email','$fone')";

}else{

    $url='index.php';
    echo("<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>");
    exit();

}

if($conexao->query($result_sql) == TRUE){
    $url='index.php';
    echo("<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>");
    exit();

}else{
    echo "Erro".$result_sql."<br>".$conexao->error;
        }
$conexao->close();
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Para casos simples, use sessões, não há nada mais simples como isso. Depois de verificares toda a informação na página de registo, define uma variável de sessão com índice `erro` ou `sucesso`:

```
if(confirmado):
   $_SESSION['mensagem'] = "Usuario cadastrado com sucesso!";
   header("location: formularioDeRegisto.php");
   exit();
else:
   $_SESSION['mensagem'] = "Ocorreu um erro durante o registo, por favor tente novamente";
   header("location: formularioDeRegisto.php");
   exit();
endif;
```

E logo na página do formulário, algures no cabeçalho do formulário, verifica se está definido alguma das mensagens, e imprime-a e apague-a de uma forma qualquer:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["mensagem"])):
   print $_SESSION["mensagem"];
   unset($_SESSION["mensagem"]);
endif;
```

> - [Mensagem para usuário após mudança de header](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101674/mensagem-para-o-usu%C3%A1rio-ap%C3%B3s-mudan%C3%A7a-de-header/101677#101677)

Answer (score 0):

Depois da linha do Insert (lá em baixo no seu aquivo `inserir_dados.php`

Coloca:

```
<script>alert("Dados Salvos com sucesso!");</script>
```

Não é a forma mais "bonita", mas de forma bem simples é isso que você deve está procurando.

Answer (score 0):

Na inserir_dados.php altere essa variável

`$url='index.php';`

por

`$url='index.php?cad=ok';`

no trecho de código indicado abaixo

```
if($conexao->query($result_sql) == TRUE){
$url='index.php?cad=ok';
echo("<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT = '0;URL=$url'>");
exit();
```

Na página do formulário coloque

```
if ($_GET["cad"]=="ok"){
  $texto = ("<p><b><font color=\"#FF0000\">Cadastro realizado com sucesso</font></b></p>");
}
```

Ai você dá um `<?php echo $texto; ?>` no lugar exato que queira que apareca na sua página.